# execution halted on R markdown compiling (error=true is set)

Tags: r-markdown, knitr

I am getting the following error when trying to knit and Rmarkdown file to word

```
Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 5, 0
Calls: <Anonymous> ... withVisible -> eval -> eval -> cbind -> cbind -> data.frame
Execution halted
```

I have all code chunks set as error=TRUE. The error appears to occur on the first line of the second code chunk (the first being setup). The first line is simply:

```
#main code####
```

What can I do, or where can I look to remedy this?

Comment: Clearly, you are creating a `data.frame` with variables that have a different number of observations.

Comment: error=true should prevent the knitr from exiting on error.